# Loading DLLs with manifest for dependencies of dependencies

Tags: windows, dll, dependencies, manifest

My situation is:

- A.dll depends on B.dll and C.dll
- B.dll depends on C.dll
- B.dll and C.dll are in a subfolder below the folder containing A.dll

B.dll and C.dll are inside an assembly (BCAssembly) with the following manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="AssemblyBC" version="1.0.0.0"/>
    <file name="B.dll"/>
    <file name="C.dll"/>
</assembly>
```

A.dll depends on AssemblyBC via its manifest, defined in A.dll's code:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"name='AssemblyBC' version='1.0.0.0' type='win32'\"")
```

When I load A.dll, I get error code 126 ("Specified module could not be found"). I have confirmed via [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) that A.dll uses the manifest to successfully find B.dll and C.dll, but B.dll cannot find C.dll. I tried adding a B.dll.manifest specifying a dependency on AssemblyBC, but this had no effect, perhaps because B.dll is inside AssemblyBC. How can I use manifests to make B.dll find C.dll?

Comment: Statically linking to A or LoadLibrary?

Comment: @Anders yes, statically linking or LoadLibrary would solve the problem, but I'm hoping to find a solution using manifests. If there's no good solution with manifests I'll go with static linking.